# using jquery in a REGULAR javascript ...script?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am not really sure how to word the question, but I basically have an old javascript that checks file extensions of a user upload BEFORE it is sent to the server for processing. (Just for the admin section of a website.)

Well, I want a div to slideDown() whenever a javascript condition returns true inside a loop (meaning, the file is good to upload).

Code so far:

```
  var thisext = fieldvalue.substr(fieldvalue.lastIndexOf('.'));
for(var i = 0; i < extension.length; i++) {
    if(thisext == extension[i]) { return true;

            $("#pleasewait").slideDown();

         }
    }
alert("Please upload ONLY .mp3 files. No other files will work.");
return false;
}
```

Comment: You don't want to just rely on JavaScript to check for this. Someone could simply turn off their JavaScript, or override your function, or do _whatever else they want_ with their client-side code, and upload a random file anyway. If you don't check for this in your server-side code, your app may blow up.

Comment: Why do you care if the files are named `.mp3`, or `.mpeg3` or `.mpeg2layer3` or `.flubber`?

Comment: @voithos I know. Agreed. But like I said, this is in a website password protected main admin section. And also, imagine hitting the upload button and then waiting 50 seconds only to see "Not valid file type."  Thats why a javascript check FIRST and then the PHP check LATER is more user friendly.

Comment: @sarnold I care because the script that plays the music only uses .mp3 files, and that is it.

Comment: @PaulHanak: Most definitely; client-side for user-friendliness, and server-side for program correctness.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code has a textbook case of a logical error. The slidedown should occur *before* the return statement because the function will exit immediately after that line.

Try this within your function:

```
var thisext = fieldvalue.substr(fieldvalue.lastIndexOf('.'));
for(var i = 0; i < extension.length; i++) {
    if(thisext == extension[i]) { 
        $("#pleasewait").slideDown();

        return true;
     }
}

alert("Please upload ONLY .mp3 files. No other files will work.");
return false;
```

Answer (score 5):

You should put `return true;` after `$("#pleasewait").slideDown();`